# Using a lead component, how to make some components still handle their own events?

Tags: codenameone

I have an InfiniteContainer list where each element is a relatively complex container with several different buttons with each their action. Since it's a scrollable list, I use LongPointerPress to activate drag and drop like Shai recommended in another post. To do this I need to set a lead component to handle this. However, when I set it, none of the other buttons get their individual events. I thought I could overwrite the getLeadComponent() of the buttons to have it return null, to ensure those buttons handle their own events, but it's private and haven't been able to think of any other solution for now.

Is there a recommended approach for handling this?

NB. I've been spending a LOT of time piecing together partial advice from different posts, and using trial and error to get this UI to work. It would be useful if the CN1 documentation could contain more explicit advice on the approaches that work for such 'real life' complex UI which combine eg lists, drag&drop, multiple buttons, long press for additional actions, Swipable containers, ... It shouldn't feel like constant hacking ;-)

Comment: Did you look thru the developer guide? http://codenameone.com/manual/ It the PDF is over 770 pages of explicit samples.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did. My point is that the manual (plus your many helpful answers in the fora) all describe specific situations individually, but when you try to piece it all together in a complex UI, it becomes really challenging to understand the interactions and get the whole thing right. Maybe a way to address this could be to add a section in the manual where you show how to re-create some real-life complex UIs, e.g. from well-known iOS/Android apps?

Comment: I think the solution for this is to use the demos as reference. The problems with "putting it all together" are always difficult and often hard to document. We're re-working the demos to include more separate pieces together but due to the nature of evolving complexity this will only solve some peoples problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can `setLeadComponent(null)` when you are done with the lead component functionality to "undo" the lead component effect. The lead component behavior is an "all or nothing" approach.

If this doesn't work for you you can override the low level events in the `Form` and implement the functionality there. You can block components from getting events by not calling `super.pointer*` methods in `Form` and thus allow any sort of effect.